# Upload image and resize problems

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to upload an image and resize it while keeping its aspect ratio, then save it to the server. I would prefer that it makes the width of the image 200px. That way the image will fill the picturebox from left to right. I am unsure how to accomplish that. Right now I am using a FileUpload control. The image gets uploaded to a stream, converted, and I want it to save to the filesystem. I know I'm doing something wrong here.

```
string type = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;

byte[] snap = new byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength];

System.IO.Stream stream = FileUpload1.FileContent;

System.Drawing.Image imageLarge = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
System.Drawing.Image imageLarge1 = ResizeImage(imageLarge, 200, 300);
MemoryStream memolarge = new MemoryStream();
imageLarge1.Save(memolarge, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memolarge);
```

Answer (score 0):

The cod you are using is correct. However, it does not consider the aspect ratio.

To calculate the aspect ratio, what you need to do is, calculate the actual width and height of the image and calculate the ratio of uploaded image.

Once you have that ratio, you need to apply that ratio to resize the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set correct height by keeping the aspect ratio.

```
int newHeight = ActualImgHeight*200/ActualImgWidth;
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200, newHeight);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmp);
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, 200, newHeight);
g.Dispose();
bmp.Save(path,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

hope this helps.